# How to set the ABL PROPATH for procedures in a JAR?

Tags: java, groovy, jar, openedge, progress-4gl

I have a Java (Groovy) CLI application that also uses some Progress ABL code. The application when built (gradle) is packaged into an executable JAR* for distribution. The r-code (compiled ABL code) is included in this JAR. I have tried setting the PROPATH a number of different ways, but I can't get it to find the r-code in the JAR. Does the r-code have to be extracted from the archive before it can be used even though the application itself is running from inside the JAR? Running the built JAR from the source code directory works fine, but I think that's just because the source .p files are in the relative path on the filesystem. How can I do this?

Is a better approach to package the r-code with the JAR in a tarball for distribution instead of including the r-code in the JAR itself? For example:

Scenario 1:

```
app.tar.gz
  -app.jar
    -Java/Groovy classes
    -Bundled dependencies
    -rcode/*.r
```

Scenario 2:

```
app.tar.gz
  -app.jar
    -Java/Groovy classes
    -Bundled dependencies
  -rcode/*.r
```

Scenario 1 leads to the PROPATH question described above, but I haven't tested Scenario 2.

*I.e. use `$ java -jar app.jar` to run the built application. I'm planning to include a startup shell script with the JAR for easy startup. The JAR main class is compiled Java which, depending on input arguments, will run one of the ABL procedures as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the r-code have to be extracted from the archive before it can be
> used even though the application itself is running from inside the
> JAR?

Short answer is yes, the AVM cannot read ABL code (source and/or r-code) in any archive other than a [procedure library](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/manage-abl/page/Procedure-libraries.html) .

> Is a better approach to package the r-code with the JAR in a tarball
> for distribution instead of including the r-code in the JAR itself?

If you use a procedure library, you will need to explicitly add the PL to `PROPATH` . If you deploy the (r-)code in (say) a zip file, you can extract it into the AVM's working directory and things should just work. It depends on what's running that ABL code, as to where the working directory is.

There are other benefits to using procedure libraries (as opposed to "loose" r-code) but I'm not sure whether they're appropriate here.